# Rapidjson assign a value of key from one document object to other document object

Tags: c++, json, c++11, rapidjson

I have two json strings parsed by Rapidjson library.

**Json 1:**

```
{
  "jKey1":{
           "jVal1Key1":{
                         "mystr":["str1","str2"]
                       },
           "jVal2Key2":["data1","data2"]
          },
  "jKey2":"Title"
}
```

**Json 2:**

```
{
    "jVal1Key1":{
                  "mystr":["str1","str2"]
                }
}
```

I just want to replace "**jVal1Key1**" of ***Json 1*** with "**jVal1Key1**" of ***Json 2***.

So I tried the following code.

```
Document doc1;
doc1.Parse<0>(json1.c_str()).HasParseError();
doc1.Parse(json1.c_str());

Document doc2;
doc2.Parse<0>(json2.c_str()).HasParseError();
doc2.Parse(json2.c_str());

if(doc1.HasMember("jKey1"))
{
    if(doc1["jKey1"].HasMember("jVal1Key1"))
    {
        if(doc2.HasMember("jVal1Key1"))
        {
           doc1["jKey1"]["jVal1Key1"] = doc2["jVal1Key1"];  // I failed here
        }
    }  
}
```

In my program, this below line,

```
doc1["jKey1"]["jVal1Key1"] = doc2["jVal1Key1"];  // I failed here
```

compiled successfully. But It fails at runtime. My question is, How can I copy the value of that key '**jVal1Key1**' of '**doc2**' to '**doc1**'.

Comment: can you add the error you get at runtime?

Comment: I catched it through std::runtime_error& . But It didn't throw any error.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [RapidJson Documentation](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#DeepCopyValue), you can do a deep copy of the DOM Tree with `CopyFrom`. Another option is to swap the values with [Swap](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#SwapValues) which is faster if speed is an issue:

**Sample Code:**

`doc1["jKey1"]["jVal1Key1"].CopyFrom(doc2["jVal1Key1"], doc2.GetAllocator());`

What I think you are doing right now is moving the value from doc2 to doc1. Look at the [Move Semantics](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#MoveSemantics) section for more information to see if that could cause the error you are seeing.